# How do i stop logout my account when i reload the page?

Tags: reactjs, reload, logout

I'm using react for web development. I'm facing auto logout problem when i refresh the page. How do i solved this problem? I'm using react router hook for front-end development and mongodb for backend.

Comment: Please provide your current auth/login code.

Comment: You'll need to implement either JWT auth method in front and back end, or session/cookies in back end, since HTTP is a stateless protocol, refresh page will erase user log in state.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.